# Specifying template arguments from variables in C++

Tags: c++, templates, rtti

I want to instantiate a template class with data types that are available at runtime in variables. For example, consider this class:

```
template <typename T, unsigned int U>
class Allocator
{
public:
    T * pointer;
    Allocator() { pointer = new T[U]; }
    ~Allocator() { delete [] pointer; }
};
```

Now I want to use it like this:

```
int main()
{
    string temp = "int";
    unsigned int count = 64;
    Allocator<temp, count> a;
    return 0;
}
```

Is there any way of doing this?

I am facing this problem in the context of serializing derived classes with base pointers. I use RTTI to identify the real type of derived class, but the information of the real type is stored in a string. My problem is to be able to dynamic_cast to the type (available as a string at runtime) from the base pointer. Please help.

Comment: Is there a reason why U has to be a template parameter instead of a parameter in the constructor?

Comment: The above is just an example of the real problem at hand. While this can be trivially solved by making U a constructor argument in this particular case, I have taken this as an example to get to the real issue ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. Data types must be known at compile time. Maybe using Boost or unions may solve the problem in a non-pretty way.

Good luck!

Comment: One of the ways that I have managed to think of is using something like a prototype pattern. If a lookup table exists for Allocators of all possible types (that are actually being used in the application), then it works to use the datatype available as string (the "key" of the table) and "clone" the appropriate Allocator (the pointer to which is the "value" for the key in the table). However, with this approach, I would still require to register pointers of say `Allocator<int, XXX>`, where XXX sweeps all possible sizes, one value at a time. Any workaround to avoid this?

Comment: Okay, after some more thought on this, I can now understand why this _cannot_ be done. The fact that code generation based on templates is a *compile time activity* is the reason. The compiler does not know the content of the variables at compile time and hence cannot figure out what code to generate when the template is instantiated. Many thanks to all for the suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

The absence of a reflection mechanism in C++ makes practically impossible the "dynamic creation" based on data with a direct language support.

The only way is to use a "switch", or any equivalent declarative mechanism, like a factory class owning a dispatch map that associate the strings declaring the type to creation function calls.

Comment: That's what I have been thinking about as well (see my comment on Drewen's answer). But the issue is, for a given data type, say `int`, I have to store pointers of Allocators of all possible size into the map. Wish there was a way to automate this ...

Comment: Meaning, have a map that stores `int` as the key and another map as its value. In the second (value) map, the key is the size (say 64), and the value is a pointer to the actual Allocator (`Allocator<int, 64> *`). Now it is easy to clone ... The flip side is that, the second (value) map has to have Allocator pointers for all possible sizes (or at least, possible sizes being used in the program).

Comment: @Somesh: I feel it a bit too convoluted, but semantically equivalent. It's nothing more than a (more articulated) declarative structures. If it makes you feel more comfortable... why not!